# python flask simple issue

Tags: python, flask

*python*:

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,redirect,url_for,session

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def h():
   if request.cookies.get("session"):
       return render_template('home.html',user=request.cookies.get("user"),time=request.cookies.get("time"))
   else:
       return redirect(url_for("form"))

@app.route('/form',methods=['GET','POST'])
def form():
   if request.method=='POST':
       u=request.form.get('username')
       p=request.form.get('password')
       if u=="nbi" and p=="1383":
           session[u]=p
           zz=make_response(render_template("home.html",user=u,time=str(datetime.now())))
           zz.set_cookie("user",u)
           zz.set_cookie("time",str(datetime.now()))
           return zz

       else:
           return render_template('deadhead.html',status=0)
   else:
       return render_template("deadhead.html")

@app.route('/logout')
def o():
   try:
       session.pop(request.cookies.get("user"))
       return redirect(url_for("deadhead"))
   except:
       return redirect(url_for("deadhead"))

if __name__=="__main__":
   app.run()
```

*deadhead.html:*

```
<body>
{% if name == 1 %}
<h1 style="color:green">welcome *_*</h1>
{% endif %}

{% if name == 0 %}
<h1 style="color:red"> error loging in "_ </h1>
{% endif %}
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method='POST'>
<input type="text" name="username: ">
<input type="text" name="password: ">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*home.html:*

```
<body>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/logout">logout</a>
<h1>welcome mon ami   french</h1>
<h3>username : {{user}}  </h3>
<h3>time login : {{time}}
</body>
</html>
```

ok,me issues are the error 405 that says:

*Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.*

this happens when i go to the home route (i mean "/")

and another error code that i get is 500 and it says:

*Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

i might still have other problems that i dont know yet if you catch the problems plz tell me and if u know the solution solve it plz *_* thank you :)

Comment: For the error 500, you will have to look at your log to have details about it. For the error 405, my guess is it happens when you post your form, as it targets `/` and I doubt index allows POST

Comment: you need to change `action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/"` and change the login method, as your are not loading data in forum , here is [link which might help you](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-flask-part-2-creating-a-login-page/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of them was caused by parameter "name" in your deadhead.html template that not defined in your render_template(). But try to set DEBUG=1 to get better error messages